# Browser Validation Error from a web service

Tags: web-services, security, mobile

I have developed a mobile app that logs into a third party web service via a rest call. Something has just changed at the web service that is now stopping my app from logging in.

When my app tries to log in it now gets a "Browser Validation Error 54” error. From what I have been able to glean online this might be caused by a "DDoS Protection Service”. I understand that this necessitates some back and forth between the web service and the client to try to verify that it is actually a browser.

It appears the way to fix this is to do the login via a web view in the mobile app instead of a direct call.

I have experimented with adding a web view to my app, and while I successfully log in the app still is getting errors on any subsequent calls to the web service.

What steps does my app need to perform to satisfy the web service?

Comment: I doubt the web service cares about web or mobile clients. It only cares about clients. As long as you do a proper request to it, the call should work. There is most likely some flow to login and you are not hitting all the proper steps. The "Browser Validation Error 54" might be misleading. Try troubleshooting it from [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), for example. Also, what service is this? Does it have proper documentation explaining what "Browser Validation Error 54" means?

Comment: The web service does not support third party clients - in fact they are expressly discouraged. There is no documentation and I have had to reverse engineer all the APIs by watching network traffic browser from their web app via the Chrome debugger.

Comment: I am using a http tester tool RapidAPI and when I call the Login API it returns an error 403 and a web page is displayed that says: Browser Validation
Error 54
This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.
Please stand by, while we are checking your browser...

Comment: After 5-10 seconds a redirect url does arrive and the RapidAPI tool asks if I want to open it in Safari. When I say yes a web page is displayed that says We're sorry this page is no longer available.

Comment: If the web service is built to not work with other clients, then it's not really a web service but just an API. But that aside, it will be hard to get help here for something that isn't documented and that you are trying to reverse engineer. I get there is some handshake in place to connect successfully. You will have to persist in finding out what step you might be missing or doing wrong. Have you tried to use Selenium to record and replay a working scenario? You might then export the test in a language it supports and look inside the saved files to see what it is doing.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used Selenium, but see if this helps: https://expleoacademy.com/int/6-steps-to-create-and-export-selenium-ide-tests/